# Using if in tables (spreadtab, tabu)

Tags: tables, ifthenelse

I was trying to build a document with a table which could change its rows depending on whether the customer needs to pay tax or not. I tried to go with

http://handyfloss.net/2007.08/latex-programming-how-to-implement-conditionals/

but this does not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,ngerman]{dinbrief}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{fp}
\RequirePackage{spreadtab}
\RequirePackage{numprint}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\newif\ifbrutto\bruttotrue

\newcommand{\rechnungLang}[4]{
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabu} to \linewidth{ l
                                        X[l]
                                        S[table-format=3.4, detect-all, round-integer-to-decimal, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]
                                    }}
    @{Date}             & @{            Text}                               & @{Volumen}        \\
                        &                                                   & @{[#3]}       \\
    #1
    @                   & @{            Gesamtleistung [#3]: }              & sum(c2:[0,-1]) \\
    @                   & @{\mdseries   Einzelpreis [EUR/#2]: }             & #4 \\
\ifbrutto
    @                   & @{\mdseries   Rechnungsbetrag (netto) [EUR]: }    & [0,-2] * [0,-1] \\
    @                   & @{\mdseries   19\% Umsatzsteuer [EUR]: }          & 0.19 * [0,-1] \\
    \rowfont\bfseries
    @                   & @             Rechnungsbetrag (brutto) [EUR]:     & sum([0,-2]:[0,-1]) \\
\else
    \rowfont\bfseries
    @                   & @             Rechnungsbetrag (netto) [EUR]:      & [0,-2] * [0,-1] \\
\fi
\end{spreadtab}
}

\begin{document}

\bruttotrue

\rechnungLang{
@27.03.2019 (Mi.)   &@ Text1                        & 0.25          \\
@27.03.2019 (Mi.)   &@ Text2                        & 0.25/2        \\
}{Stunde}{Stunden}{10}

\bruttotrue

\rechnungLang{
@27.03.2019 (Mi.)   &@ Text1                        & 0.25          \\
@27.03.2019 (Mi.)   &@ Text2                        & 0.25/2        \\
}{Stunde}{Stunden}{10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: avoid the tabu package, it is broken. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ok, how to I build the table without tabu? (Unfortunately, tabu is by far the best table-package by far, regarding API and features.)

Comment: Switching to `{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l, X, ...` did not help.